# Which driver for film scanner Plustek OpticFilm 8100?

Tags: drivers, scanner, dia

I own a film scanner Plustek OpticFilm 8100 but cannot find a suitable driver to use it in Linux OS.
This scanner is not supported by SANE neither by VueScan.
Specifically, my OS is Ubuntu 18.04.
How to solve this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Install virtualbox. Install windows xp/7/10 guest and use scanner there.
I own plustek 8100 and the only way to use it is windows or mac.

EDIT: VueScan not supporting this device on linux https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/plustek_opticfilm_8100.html#technical-information

EDIT 2023: VueScan now works on Linux without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2021, [Vuescan](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/plustek_opticfilm_8100.html) does support the OpticFilm 8100 on Linux!

I've got the mostly identical 8200i and after some initial testing, it seems to work just fine. I've downloaded the .deb, installed it on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, plugged in the scanner and that's it. Files produced by the trial version are watermarked – seems like film scanning requires the more expensive professional version.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree: [vuescan](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/vuescan.htm#plustek) has  Plustek OpticFilm 8100  [listed](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/vuescan.htm#plustek).

To make it a bit more complete:

- [download](https://www.hamrick.com/download.html) (tgz)
- [Linux release notes](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/vuescan.htm#linux)

1 problem... [it is not free](https://www.hamrick.com/reg.html).

> CAN I TRY VUESCAN BEFORE I BUY?
>
> You can test VueScan with your scanner for as long as you'd like without buying it first. We're sure you'll find VueScan to be useful, so we also offer a 30-day conditional money back guarantee after you buy VueScan

Standard Edition costs 39.95 USD. Professional editition 89.95.

I would suggest to install it and try if it works. If that fails I agree with Dainius Sakalinskas: use virtualbox with Windows

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but VueScan software does not support Plustek Optic Film 8100 for Linux OS. I bought the Windows version and scan all my film from Windows OS (I do not want any Wine environment). Maybe I'll try with VirtualBox.